# iOS: Remove UIImageView instances created by an NSArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, nsarray, sigabrt

I have an NSArray named imgBall that holds a temporary variable name imgView, which displays an image on the screen when the user touches a point on the screen.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 40, 40)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    imgView.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    [imgBall addObject:imgView];
}
```

The user can create multiple instances by touching anywhere on the screen. Could mean 5, 10, or 20 different balls in the array.

Now, i have a button that needs to 'clear' the screen and remove all instances of imgView.
I have tried the following:

```
 for (UIImageView *imgView in imgBall) {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview:imgView]; 
}
```

and

```
    for (UIImageView *imgView in imgBall) {
    [imgBall removeObject:imgView];
}
```

But they both yield SIGABRT and throw the exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 
'*** Collection     <__NSArrayM: 0x735f4a0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

What way can i do this without getting SIGABRT thrown every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
for (UIImageView *imgView in imgBall) {
    [imgView removeFromSuperview]; 
    [imgBall removeObject:imgView];
}
```

**You also need to do [imgView release]** after [imgBall addObject:imgView] when you create it in touchesEnded, otherwise you will leak memory.

Comment: @nworksdev You may want to call `[imgBall removeAllObjects]` after removing all the UIImageViews as well.

Comment: Got it, i was just about to ask about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
for (UIImageView *imgView in imgBall)
{
[imgView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And then don´t forget to release and set the array imgBall to nil to avoid memory issues. If it´s a NSMutableArray, just call removeAllObjects.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer clicking the checkmark =D to the answer you prefer, of course

Comment: I think you menat `[imgView removeFromSuperview];`

Answer (score 1):

You should do this like...

```
for (UIImageView *imgView in imgBall) {
    [imgView removeFromSuperview];
}
[imgBall removeAllObjects];
```